# Javascript on loaded page not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
// Change the value of the outputText field
function setAjaxOutput(){
    if(httpObject.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById('maincontent').innerHTML = httpObject.responseText;
    }
}
```

i try to load a page which contain this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
alert('dfd');
$("#formAddUser").validate({
    rules: {
        userImage: {
            required: true,
            accept: "png|jpg|gif|jpeg"
        }
    }
});
});
</script>

<div class="content-box">
<div class="content-box-header">
........................
```

Why javascript on loaded page not executed? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that you are getting HTML via setAjaxOutput(), then embedding it in the page and finding that the script tags are not executed?

Comment: yes, script on the embedded page not executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that innerHTML doesn't execute scripts in the HTML fragment. When you say 'element.innerHTML = htmlfragment;', it just adds the tags and renders the HTML. Script tags are not rendered as part of the HTML by the browser, so they are ignored.

You need to use [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) instead of jQuery.ajax() like this:

```
$('#maincontent').load('yourscript.php');
```

jQuery.load(); has code inside that first takes those tags out, then adds the remaining HTML via innerHTML, then runs the tags separately. You can see the code that does this [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js) at around line 211. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed.

Comment: Thank you Matt Gibson, nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

first try:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    alert('dfd');

    </script>
```

and then try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('dfd');

    });

</script>
```

and paste the results.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your form comes with ajax. so it is better if you can turn your validation into a function, and call it inside ajax loaded content.

Comment: could you give me an example, i'm sorry, still newbie

Comment: do you mean tobe like this
function setAjaxOutput(){
    if(httpObject.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById('maincontent').innerHTML = httpObject.responseText;
        alert("test");//call function
    }
}
it works, but i this function can no longer be a global function, i've to specify for each page that i want to load.

Comment: well, in a js file, write a function like: `function validate_no_matter() { // your validation goes here, ie select form id, validate fields at cetra, }`. Include this js file in your main page. `<script src=....>` then in both in your main page and ajax loaded page run the script like: `<script type="text/javascript">validate_no_matter();</script>`. In your main page you can call it in document ready. Yet, in ajax page you need to call it like above at the end of the document.